# Can't I remove 'the' before world in the given sentence?

Tags: grammar, definite-article

Sentence - You are a unique creature in 'the' world.

Can I omit the word 'the' when it is already known that I am referring to world which is already understood ?

Note - There is already an answer that tells about Earth and the Earth related to my question but I didn't understand it.

Comment: Please note that we do not edit or correct text. But we never just say: in world.